# Where to store password in react js MERN stack?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, axios, mern

I am learning React so if someone would please help with this question would be great!

I am building a small application that will be used privately thus I will **not** create a Registration/Sign up form. I will have **only** a **login** area, with some restricted info behind it.

I am using MERN stack so I tried to create a new DB In MongoDb to store a username and a password (that I hashed) and saved it as a string.
So in my frontend in React I was planning to hash the user input and match that against the DB.

I think that maybe there are better ways of doing this or even a library for that.
I will only have one user (admin) logging in, thus no need to register and store passwords, I just need this one username/password saved.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you only ever need one "user account", rather than username (which is irrelevant if you have no users to distinguish _between_) and password you could specify a single administrative password as e.g. an environment variable. But the right options will depend on your context, which we know very little about.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So you suggest I hide these under variables in this .env file is that right?

Comment: That would be one way to supply the value in your development environment, yes.